# How to select a field with spring-data-couchbase

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I'm starting to try spring-data-couchbase.
To do that, I work on the sample bucket beer-sample.
And I would like in my BeerRepository return the list of all beer style.
So the result is a List of String.
Is it possible to do that with Spring-data ? And how ?

Thanks

Comment: Write some code and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use projections to just read some attributes of the entity. For reading just the style, create an interface exporting style and add custom method to the repository returning the interface. 
More documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_dto_projections).